# domain name and spring boot application deployment

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have developed an application that has two parts:

```
applicant -> localhost:8081/applicant-api
 approver -> localhost:8082/approver-api
```

and then I deployed it on a windows server which has a public address. now I can access my platform on the web.

```
applicant -> 197.241.211.36:8081/applicant-api
 approver -> 197.241.211.36:8082/approver-api
```

and then I asked my provider to give me a domain name so I can connect like this.

```
applicant -> monsite.com:8081/applicant-api
 approver -> monsite.com:8082/approver-api
```

so I didn't want that, I only wanted to type in the domain name like this.

Please help me as I have to do this. I will not be able to ask my visitors to enter even with port 8081.

N.B. for deployment on windows I make two separate jar to launch my application.

Comment: `Setup IIS with URL Rewrite as a reverse proxy for real world apps` (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a reverse proxy that listens on your server for all incoming calls to `monsite.com` and based on the path redirects the calls to one of the 2 applications. The most popular ones are Apache and Nginx. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with configuring and managing these on Windows, but you can start from the links below.

https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-configure-Apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnetcore/practice-troubleshoot-linux/2-2-install-nginx-configure-it-reverse-proxy

A proxy like this enables you to do a lot of things, like SSL termination for the whole domain in a central place. It is worth getting to know a bit about them.